# Resource use of threading.Lock.acquire() in python

Tags: multithreading

How much resource python use to wait threading.Lock.acquire()?
Little or Absolutely zero?
Internally, how often threading module check for Lock.locked()?

## while another thread is holding lock...

```
lck = threading.Lock()

# code 1
n = 1e-3
while lck.locked():
    time.sleep(n)

# code 2
lck.acquire()
lck.release()
```

Do code 1 and 2 have big gap for using CPU resources?